# How to implement Forgerock AM with Spring security with Authentication and Autherization?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openam, forgerock

I want to secure my Spring boot rest api using Forgerock OpenAm with Spring Security.
But I am not able to find any resources for that.
If anyone has any clarity on this. Help me with any demo project.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably plenty of ways to do that: Some Forgerock plugins, let gateways do the AuthX, SAML2, OAuth2/OIDC, ...

The way I'd recommend is to stick to standards - because they are interchangeable and you can apply them to any application or use them with every modern identity provider.

I personally favor OIDC (aka. OpenID Connect, which is based on OAuth2) for an SSO in applications. There are plenty of good resources on how to setup OIDC/OAuth2 with OpenAM and same for Spring Security.

Here are some links that will help you to learn about it:

- To learn about OIDC the standard has a pretty good website linking to good resources: https://openid.net/connect/
- Same for OAuth2: https://www.oauth.com
- Baeldung Spring Security OIDC example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect
- OIDC Guide for OpenAM by Forgerock: https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/OpenID+Connect+Quick+Start